# Simple SQL Reporting Services Question

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I'm just writing up a feasibility study for a project and before I go in too deep, can I get a .net program to get a list of reports for a server in SQL Reporting Services?

In other words, if someone adds a new report, we want it to show in the list. Also, can you get information in detail about the report via some sort of enumeration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access all this data via the Reporting Services Web Service. You'll have to create a proxy object first but once that is done, getting a list of reports is simple. For example:

```
ReportingService2005 service = new ReportingService2005();
service.Url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportingServicesURL"];
service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
CatalogItem[] items = service.ListChildren(reportingServicesfolderPath, false);
List<string> reports = new List<string>(items.Length);
foreach (var item in items)
{
    reports.Add(item.Name);
}
return reports;
```

Answer (score 1):

Reporting Services has a SOAP API, so you can retrieve lists of reports via that, but I think it'd be easier to go directly to the database. The `Catalog` table in the `ReportServer` database contains a list of every report. You can even link from there to the `ExecutionLog` table to find out when it was run (although that table seems to be a sliding window of about three months - you won't get execution details older than that).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read up [Integrating Reporting Services into Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153697.aspx). After all the Reporting Service is a WebService endpoint, so you can use SOAP WebService endpoints or HTTP calls. Besides that there is the [Reporting Services Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281387.aspx) library and last there is the [Reporting Services WMI Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152957.aspx). Afaik each of the above libraries allow you to do what you asked.